# Adding an additional field to contact form

Tags: php, html, ajax, contact-form

I would like to add the additional text field 'Telephone Number' to my contact form. The contact form already-existed from a Bootstrap template I am using and is working perfectly without my addition. I may have written the PHP wrong.

Without any changes to the PHP the contact form sends an e-mail with no issues.

HTML

```
<form>
    <div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail *" required="">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="number" placeholder="Telephone Number *" required="">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject *" required="">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Message *" rows="12" required=""></textarea>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>
                <input class="btn btn-block btn-brand" type="submit" value="Send Message">
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<!-- Ajax response-->
<div class="ajax-response text-center" id="contact-response"></div>
```

PHP

```
  // Mail settings
    $to      = "example@gmail.com";


    // You can put here your email
    $header = "From: example@gmail.com\r\n";
    $header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $header.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";

    if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["number"]) && isset($_POST["subject"]) && isset($_POST["message"])) {

        $content  = "Name: "        . $_POST["name"]    . "\r\n";
        $content .= "Email: "       . $_POST["email"]   . "\r\n";
        $content .= "Number: "      . $_POST["number"]   . "\r\n";
        $content .= "Subject: "     . $_POST["subject"]   . "\r\n";
        $content .= "Message: "     . "\r\n" . $_POST["message"];
        $subject = $_POST["subject"];

        if (mail($to, $subject, $content, $header)) {
            $result = array(
                "message"    => "Thanks for contacting us.",
                "sendstatus" => 1
            );

            echo json_encode($result);
        } else {
            $result = array(
                "message"    => "Sorry, something is wrong.",
                "sendstatus" => 0
            );

            echo json_encode($result);
        }

    }
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
(function($){

    $(document).ready(function() {

        /* ---------------------------------------------- /*
         * Contact form ajax
        /* ---------------------------------------------- */

        $('#contact-form').find('input,textarea').jqBootstrapValidation({
            preventSubmit: true,
            submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
                // additional error messages or events
            },
            submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var submit          = $('#contact-form submit');
                var ajaxResponse    = $('#contact-response');

                var name            = $('#contact-form [name="name"]').val();
                var email           = $('#contact-form [name="email"]').val();
                var phone           = $('#contact-form [name="phone"]').val();
                var message         = $('#contact-form [name="message"]').val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'assets/php/contact.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        name: name,
                        email: email,
                        phone: phone,
                        message: message,
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function(result) {
                        submit.empty();
                        submit.append('<i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i> Wait...');
                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                        if(result.sendstatus == 1) {
                            ajaxResponse.html(result.message);
                            $form.fadeOut(500);
                        } else {
                            ajaxResponse.html(result.message);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Email from contact form should send successfully.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. To be clear, are you asking how to add a field in bootstrap?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, what error message are you getting? also by the last section on the HTML your template seems to be using AJAX, coudl you post your javascript too?

Comment: @Chipster Hi, thank you! Apologies, I'm asking how to add a field in PHP. It's the Telephone number field

Comment: @JuanAntonioOrozco Thank you! I'm not getting any errors, the contact form works perfectly fine without the 'Telephone Number' field that I added so I don't feel like there is a problem with the JavaScript. With the field, you press the submit button and nothing happens

Comment: So, is bootstrap in your environment still then, or you're saying it was there once, but now you need to add it without bootstrap and send it in the email?

Comment: @JuanAntonioOrozco Thank you for the JavaScript suggestion *Big Facepalm* there is a contact form javascript file

Comment: @JuanAntonioOrozco I added the JavaScript file to the question!

Comment: @Chipster It's not really a bootstrap problem, it's more that I just wanted to add an additional field to the contact form. But I feel that I may have written the incorrect PHP

Comment: @mimmi0070, don't worry, it is something easy to miss if you don't know what to look for, also because of the AJAX interactions, the errors may be hidden on your browser console, you may open it by right-clicking anywhere on your page and selecting inspect, in the pop up window will be a tab called console (this works on all browsers)

Comment: @JuanAntonioOrozco It's odd because the console doesn't flag up any errors...

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML and PHP code, your phone number field its called `number` but your javascript its looking for a field named "Phone" as seen in the following line of code:

```
var phone           = $('#contact-form [name="phone"]').val();
```

what I would suggest you is to change it on your HTML and PHP so the field it's named "phone" as javascript expects

what is happening is that the javascript code it's taking only the specific fields listed on the code and then passing then to PHP, but as it does not matches the name, that field it's left behind, it does not appear to the PHP script, and as it is empty, the validation fails

Comment: Hi Juan, unfortunately it still doesn't work... I have added 'phone' instead of 'number' on both of my HTML and PHP files